# Left Join Linq query gives Null reference exception

Tags: linq, lightswitch-2012

[image]  This is inside a wcf ria service class for my light switch application.i just cannot figure why this exception occurs at run time when running the lightswitch application.how can i get rid of this for this query to run.pls help

Both loan and release table were created using lightswitch inside lightswitch.relationship between loan and release is one to zero or one i.e one loan can have one release.this query itself is from a previous SO question i came accross

```
    [Query(IsDefault = true)]
    public IQueryable<PendingLoans> GetPendingLoans()
    {
        var query = from c in this.context.Loans
                  join p in this.context.Releases
                  on c.Id equals p.Loan.Id into cp
                  from p in cp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new PendingLoans
                  {
                      Billno=c.BillNo,

                      releaseid = p == null ? 0 : p.Id
                  };
        return query.AsQueryable();


    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check if this.context is set.

Comment: I'd break this into several statements (no `linq`) and see where's the problem: E.g.: var loans = this.Context.Loans; One of `linq`'s cons is the debugging.

Comment: I would look at `p.Loan` and see if there are `Releases` that don't have a `Loan`.

Comment: @Enigmativity relationship is defined such that a release must have loan and a loan can have zero or one releases.